# Create a SSL certificate with openssl

Tags: ssl, openssl, pki, pfx, csr

I'm working with a partner who ask me a SSL certificate (for web in order to put SAML for a webapp).

He sent me a CSR file.
With that I generate a cer file (with my pki http://pkiserver/certsrv I also converted it in crt file (just in case).

I generated a keyfile file.key with a passphrase (with openSSL)

So I understand correctly I need now to generate a pfx file for my partner. I don't know how it works with open SSL

I do not understand this command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certificat-ssl.cer -certfile cert-intermediaire.cer -certfile cert-racine.cer -inkey cle-privee.key -export -out certificat-ssl.pfx
```

After the -in "is my crt file ? -certfile I don't know what to put here
-inkey my file.key which I've generated -export the famous file I want

Comment: If he has provided you with a CSR (signing Request) he already has a key - you just need to use your CA to sign the request, which will generate the certificate. You should not need the key at all - it's private!

Comment: This question isn't about programming.  It would be better on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

From the URL of your CA server, I'll assume you're using a Microsoft CA.

The partner has sent you a CSR.  That means they have the private key at their location, therefore there is no reason for you to generate one for them - assuming that is what you mean by *keyfile*.

All you need to do is sign the CSR with your Microsoft CA and export the certificate as a PEM file.

Once you've returned the certificate to the partner, they can install it.  If that means they need to pair the certificate with the private key and create a PKCS#12 file, then so be it; but that is a task for them, not you, as you don't want to be handling *their* private key.

To clarify the OpenSSL command, just in-case you need to explain it to your partner organisation:

`openssl pkcs12` tells the utility that you're working with PKCS#12 files;

`-certfile cert-intermediaire.cer` is the subordinate (or intermediate) CA certificate. This is your Microsoft CA's certificate.  If you have a three-tier PKI, simply add more `-certfile` options to cover all your CA certificates.  If you have a single-tier PKI, remove either this or the next option (both are `-certfile`)

`-certfile cert-racine.cer` is the Root CA certificate (the certificate which signed your CA's certificate).  There is normally no need to send this certificate within the PKCS#12 file as your partner should have received and installed this through a more formal process which should involve the checking of the authenticity of the file and the trustworthiness of your organisation's PKI.  On the other hand, there is no harm in sending it.

`-in certificat-ssl.cer` is the certificate that you generated for them with your CA;

`-inkey cle-privee.key` is the private key that only your partners should hold (which is why they should be running this command);

`-export` tells the utility that it is exporting a new PKCS#12 file;

`-out certificat-ssl.pfx` is the filename to which you are exporting.

Comment: Hi garethTheRed         thank you so much for all your explanaitions so if i understand i just have to connect https://mypki/certsrv > ask a new certificate paste the famous CSR and then i'll get the PEM file ?

Comment: That just about sums it up, yes.  Then send that PEM file to your partners along with your CA certificate(s) in PEM format and let them do what they wish with them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !